# Make node colors darker in NetworkX

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I wanted to make nodes in Networkx darker/more solid because right now the nodes are transparent and the edges are visible on the node itself.

The edges are  are starting from the middle of the node.
So, I wanted to either make the nodes darker so **the edges aren't visible IN the node itself or make the edges start from the outside of the node.**

Nodes look like this currently:

[image]

I tried increasing the alpha value to 1 but it is still transparent not solid.

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=1200, node_color=colors,alpha=1)
```

Comment: I suspect that, `colors` in `node_color=colors` has some alpha values.

Comment: This is what colors is: for n in G.nodes():                                       
`if n in set1:         G.nodes[n]['color'] = '#7a8eff'                                          else:         G.nodes[n]['color'] = '#730a15'  colors = [node[1]['color'] for node in G.nodes(data=True)]`